# No of non negative integer solutions of an equation

Tags: combinatorics

I came to a problem of finding no of non negative integer solutions of a given equation.

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_r = n$$

I found the solution on internet using stars and bars and got it. But I want to know the flaw in my approach.

My approach:

I assumed all variables to be like containers. so the solution should be like no of combinations of $n$ containers out of $r$ different types of containers where repetition is allowed. So now every container can be selected in $r$ ways. So total no of permutation should be $r^n$.

Is this the right approach or I am missing something ? How can I derive combination out permutation now as elements are being repeated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n=2$, $r=2$. Then in your solution you have two items and two containers. But in order to get $r^n$ you would need to count

- First item in container $1$, second item in container $2$
- First item in container $2$, second item in container $1$

as different possibilities, even though they both represent the *same* solution to your original equation, namely $1+1=2$.

Comment: So if I derive combination out of r^n permutaution, I should get the solution. So, no of combinations should be r^n/n! . But that is far away from required answer.

Comment: @krrish: No, because not every solution to the original equation is counted $n!$ times. For example $r^n$ counts the solution $2+0=2$ only once, namely as "First item in container $1$, second item in container $1$". When different solutions are counted different numbers of times, adjusting for overcounting is not simple, and is rarely the way to go.

Comment: Got your point, thanks. Please enlighten if any other approach than star and bars can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: @krrish: No, the stars-and-bars reasoning is the standard solution for this problem. Once you know the answer you can also prove it by induction on $r$, using properties of Pascal's triangle, but that is hardly any more enlightening.